# How to ensure type in a generic implements some operators in Dart?

Tags: generics, dart

I want to build a generic class which contains objects of type `T`. The containing class must execute some operators on these objects, specifically operators like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. How can I ensure that the objects' type implements these operators?

Specifically, I'm implementing a matrix class, as in mathematical matrices. I could have allowed only `double` elements, but I want to be able to also make matrices of custom numeric classes like rational numbers or complex numbers (this is part of a larger project).

My current implementation has the signature

```
class Matrix<T extends MatrixElement> {
  final int _rows;          // The number of rows
  final int _cols;          // The number of columns
  ...
  final List<T> _elements;  // Matrix data, [i*step+j] is row i, col j.
```

Where `MatrixElement` is an abstract class with operators like

```
dynamic operator + (dynamic other);
```

I could have changed the Matrix class to simply `class Matrix<T> { ... }`, but then errors can arise at runtime and Dart Editor is filled with warnings about the operators not being defined for the class `Object`.

What my intuition says is something like `class Matrix<T implements MatrixElement> { ... }`, but Dart doesn't seem to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do is just assume that the elements have these methods and leave the type parameter unbounded. That will get rid of the warnings, though it's probably a bit unsatisfying when you want the type system to help you out.

Union types would help, so here's the bug you can star: http://dartbug.com/4938

Comment: Thank you! I adjusted my formulation in the question, because I meant to say that the warnings are there if i do not specify any type for T to extend (have it unbounded) (it's what I tried initially, before adding the `extends MatrixElement` part).

Comment: Accepted your answer, as it's probably the best one can get. Coming from writing in Go for the last year, I miss how Go uses interfaces for handling types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do to define interfaces:

```
  abstract class MatrixElement {
    dynamic operator + (dynamic other);
  }
```

Then you define

```
class Matrix<T extends MatrixElement> {}
```

Last for my type I implement the class MatrixElement:

```
class MatrixDouble implements MatrixElement {
    dynamic operator + (dynamic other) {
         return this.double + other;
    }
}
```

And T should have the operator.